# AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'project_gdf'

Tags: python, plot, module, attributes, osmnx

I've successfully downloaded the 0.14.0 version of osmnx.

But have this error from output: AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'project_gdf'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPolygon

yerevan = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/Python/DataScience/data/Yerevan") 
city=ox.gdf_from_place("Yerevan,Armenia",which_result=2)
city=ox.project_gdf(city)
fig, ax=ox.plot_shape(city)
```

What can I do to solve this problem? My Python version is 3.8.3

Comment: Use `city = ox.projection.project_gdf(city)` instead of `city = ox.project_gdf(city)`

Comment: @Anwarvic, then I have this output `ValueError: All geometries in GeoDataFrame must be shapely Polygons or MultiPolygons`

Comment: Try `ax = city.plot()` instead of `fig, ax=ox.plot_shape(city)`

Comment: Then there is no any error, but still it is not bringing me any plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
city = ox.gdf_from_place("Yerevan, Armenia", which_result=2)
city = ox.projection.project_gdf(city)
ax = city.plot()
_ = ax.axis('off')
```

Most of OSMnx's module functions are available directly in the `ox.` namespace as a shortcut. But any that aren't, are available via `ox.module_name.function_name()`. See [docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for more info.

Also note that the `plot_shape` function was deprecated with a user warning in a previous release and will be removed in the upcoming release.

Also also note that `which_result=2` geocodes your query to the center point of Yerevan. Is that your desired behavior? If you want the boundary polygon of Yerevan, do not pass that parameter or pass it as `which_result=1`.

Comment: No. See updated note in answer. You are specifically asking it to give you the 2nd geocoding result.

Comment: thanks for the answer, my problem was that I used `graph_from_place` instead of `gdf_from_place` and I kept wondering why it produces `MultiDiGraph` instead of `GeoDataFrame`

Comment: @gboeing, any ideas why it works in Jupyter and not work in Pycharm?

Comment: Not without full details to diagnose your environment(s). But I'd guess different environments or kernels running in different places.